Is there a way with redocly to customize the HTML output such that the version number does not show?
Redocly generates docs using the redocly build-docs which ingests OpenAPI yaml and outputs an html file. In the generated html file there is a version string generated into the header <h1>MyTitle <span>(info.version)</span></h1> which is sourced from info.version

The OpenAPI 3.1 spec requires an Info Object to be defined.
The info object requires a version field.

Failure to define info.version means you will not pass an OpenAPI lint. However, deleting the version number generates the html output as desired. Redocly just ignores version and generates the HTML without it.
The problem is our build system which assigns a build number is different from our sandbox which doesn't have a version number yet. Is there a way to conceal the inclusion of info.version in the generated docs such that version number can exist in the .yaml file as required by the spec, but be absent from the generated .html file. Does redocly support theming to hide the version number from the output?

this should get you there.. modify the code to target the info.version
https://redocly.com/docs/cli/custom-plugins/custom-decorators#decorator-example

Something similar to this based on my comment
plugins/decorators/hide-info-version.js
module.exports = HideInfoVersion;

function HideInfoVersion() {
  console.log("removing Info.version");
  return {
    Info: {
      leave(target) {
        if(target.version) {
          delete target.version;
        }
      }
    },
  }
};

plugins/index.js
const HideInfoVersion = require('./decorators/hide-info-version.js');

// this is our custom identifier
const id = 'myUniqueId';

const decorators = {
  oas3: {
    'hideInfoVersion': HideInfoVersion
  }
};

module.exports = { id, decorators };

redocly.yaml
plugins:
  - "./linting/plugins/index.js"

decorators:
  myUniqueId/hideInfoVersion: on


the id is our internal code, but it's the same as I mentioned in the answer.


\
 | redocly.yaml
 \---linting
    \---plugins
       |   index.js
       \---decorators
          | hide-info-version.js


I get a warning "Deprecated plugin format detected: myUniqueId" I also fixed a few errors in your answer that stopped this from even running, but alas I don't see it working.  and I do't see your debug statement "removing Info.version"

i just tried it and it works. (with the code fixes you made (sorry :) ))

the deprecated thing is id used to be defined outside of the function.. it still works though

I'm not sure what you mean when you say "id is our internal code" where is this internal code being set? Are you saying redocly has an internal code that I set up somewhere? I just copied and pasted all your things as-is. I assumed myUniqueId was for the plugin and I could change it so long as i followed the change through in .redocly. But I didn't change it. I kept everything as you posted.

the redocly.yaml should be at the root and I have an intermediate folder linting at the root which has decorators and index.js

i have id in the index.js in plugins folder.

RIght, so do I I didn't change anything you provided. I used it all exactly as you had typed it (with my fixes). no joy. =(

it finds all this stuff, Deprecated plugin format detected: myUniqueId but my <h1> in the output still has a version string.

i used bundle in the cli... i wonder if build-docs doesn't recognize the decorator.  let me check

Be very weird if it didn't use the decorates but it did generate the deprecated plugin format error. Also the pre-shipped remove-x-internal decorator 100% works.

appears it doesn't work with build-docs..  https://github.com/Redocly/redocly-cli/issues/1418

I got the answer, see my submission above. This system is crazy complex. If you file two bugs, (1) on getting Deprecated plugin format detected: myUniqueId when the plugin isn't used, and on (2) the plugin created not working on build-docs when it works on bundle. And you file them upstream, I'll bounty this answer 500 points. Since I'm sick of messing with that and went to far down that rabbit hole. Either way, creating a plugin is remarkably hard to grok in that case.

Also may be worth looking at https://github.com/Redocly/redocly-cli/blob/ebbcddc832b0c4fb800703671d0ca0f0efff32e9/packages/core/src/decorators/common/info-override.ts#L8 to see how core does this.

the deprecated message is probably originating from the plugins keyword, not the decorators keyword because it loads the plugins and that's where the id is defined.

info-override
All that's needed is for you to use the core plugin info-override. Like this,
decorators:
  info-override:
    version: null

Then redocly will generate the docs without the version number.

that only works for bundle.  not build-docs

doesn't work with build-docs .. https://github.com/jeremyfiel/redocly-decorator-test/tree/build-docs

@JeremyFiel you're right. I was calling redocly bundle by proxy of openapi bundle. So bundle was always in my pipeline. I'm not sure then why your custom one did not work.
